# P0106 error in a brand new car

Tags: engine, fiat, punto

i have a brand new car:

> Fiat Punto street 1.2 69CV

just This morning after 1 min after start the engine, it wasn't at full power and i had the error "check the engine" then with my program : "torque" i inspected the message and i found the problem here:
http://www.dtcsearch.com/P0106/?from=Torque
I cannot understand about this problem what is caused, but after stopped the car and restart it worked fine.
Do i need to warry about this? Do i need do something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the car to the dealer where you bought it from, and save their time by telling that you have scanned already the error code. Really, if the car is brand new, it still has its warranty and the dealership should fix whatever problems you have.

Your error code refers to the manifold absolute pressure sensor, which may be faulty. I suspect the dealership will probably replace this sensor. I had a similar problem with the lambda sensor while there was still warranty left, and replacement fixed the issue.

Why your car works without this sensor is simple: there is an abundance of sensors in a modern engine, and failure of one sensor still allows intelligent decisions to be made by estimating what the value would be based on readings from other sensors.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, the car dealer replied that there are several reasons for this: 1) dirty LGP, 2)i didn't wait on the start the signal, 3)the carburetor had a lag.